# Loading multiple versions of python module - like dlls

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have python program that evaluates experiments. So there are several versions of module with some changes, my program needs to start each one and get some data from it. In C world, I would just load 10 different dlls and I'd be happy, however in python You cannot unload module. Reload works, but just for single files, so I would need to keep track of what is imported inside modules (impossible because of conditional imports).

What is pythonic way of dealing with this problem (other than separate interfaces).

Comment: I'm a bit confused, but i think you can just load in a class from your module and make different instances of that class

Comment: Do the versions have different names? If they do, just import them as if they were different modules. If not, they should.

Comment: They do not have different names. This is just one module in dozens of versions, that need to be evaluated (machine learning models).

Comment: Why not give them different names? Say, add suffixes for version numbers.

Comment: Module has dozens of files, renaming all classes would be pointless.